# How to get individuals data property value in sparql

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege, protege4

Hi i am in new to ontologies. I have developed a restaurant ontology by Protege software. But I badly need a SPARQL query that finds property values for all individuals of a class.

[image: protege screenshot]

I want to get a result like:

```
Angels_n_Gypsies
House #30, Rd No. 19/A, Dhaka 1213, Bangladesh
```

[image: graph image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just follow the property values...

```
SELECT ?rname ?lname
WHERE {
   ?inst a :Popular_restaurant .
   ?inst :restaurant_name ?rname .
   ?inst :Location_name ?lname .
}
```

But that's just the end result.  A way to understand SPARQL is to start pedantically.  For example:

```
SELECT ?inst
WHERE {
   ?inst a :Popular_restaurant .
}
```

That gets you all members of the class :Popular_restaurant.  Then find what properties are defined for each member:

```
SELECT ?inst ?p ?o
WHERE {
   ?inst a :Popular_restaurant .
   ?inst ?p ?o .
}
```

And the bindings for `p` will tell you what properties are defined for members of this class.  So use those values to continuously refine the query.

Comment: Thanks mate u save my day